# Nginx rewrite - how do I replace whitespaces with hypens?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, spaces

I have URLs that look like this:

`http://somesite.com/directory/subdirectory/This Path Looks Like This/So Does this one`

I want to replace the spaces with hyphens so it looks like this:

`http://somesite.com/directory/subdirectory/This-Path-Looks-Like-This/So-Does-this-one`

I've looked around the Internet using Google and Bing, but I can't find a satisfying solution at all.

Comment: Try: `rewrite "^(.*) (.*)$" $1-$2 permanent;`

Comment: I tried that, and it worked. But now it breaks the file path and I get a 404.

Comment: It does rewrite it, but because it executes a redirect, it breaks the filepath, and says "no input file specified".